# GNU pth vs. pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to build a portable and efficient server in C++; it will have lots of clients trying to connect at the same time, so it must be able of handling each request parallel.

I have been trying to find documentation, guides... etc. for multithreading. I have found a lot about POSIX Pthread, but almost nothing for GNU Pth (apart from the official manual in gnu.org).

So, can anyone explain me the difference between POSIX Pthread and GNU Pth? Please, I want the response not to be a copy of Wikipedia's contents (keep in mind that I'm an absolute newbie to multithreading). I want my server to be portable and efficient between all *nix-based systems, keeping away of using heavy fork()s.

Thanks for your help.

PS: I think it's better to ask this here: what about Windows? Are Pthreads or Pth an option there? If not, what is the API for that operating system?

Comment: Latest release of GNU Pth: June 2006...

Comment: Look at boost threads if you want to be cross platform.

Comment: Windows have its own native implementation of this kind of application scheduled threads built into its own Win32 API called [fibers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are API functions to convert a thread to a fiber and vice versa. They are _not_ portable to any other platform though.

Comment: I reported a fatal bug in GNU Pth's reader/writer lock implementation (with an "obviously correct" trivial fix) 12 years ago and the fix still has not been incorporated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Pthreads, it's **much** more widely used, so there is far more information and support available for it. I've never met anyone who actually uses GNU Pth. Or better yet if you are using C++11 use `std::thread` and if not then use `boost::thread`.

> So, can anyone explain me the difference between POSIX Pthread and GNU Pth?

Pthreads is a cross-platform standard for pre-emptible multithreading, meaning (usually) the OS kernel manages the threads and the OS scheduler decides when each thread gets to run (if you have a single core only one thread can run at a time, if you have multiple cores multiple threads can run at a time).  The OS scheduler could pause any thread at (almost) any time and let another thread run, so each thread gets a limited "time slice" and then other threads get to run.

GNU Pth is a *non-preemptible* user-space threading library, meaning the threads and which ones run at which time are decided in user-space not by the kernel.  Some people say programs using non-preemptible threading libraries are easier to understand, because your thread won't get paused at arbitrary times for another thread to run.

> I want my server to be portable and efficient between all *nix-based systems, keeping away of using heavy fork()s.

`fork` is not heavy on UNIX.

> what about W*ndows? Are Pthreads or Pth an option there? If not, what is the API for that operating system?

There are pthreads APIs for Windows, but they're not native to the Windows OS. I don't know if GNU Pth works on Windows - I doubt it, unless you use Cygwin.  Windows has its own Win32 thread model.

Using `std::thread` or `boost::thread` is portable to POSIX platforms and Windows, and makes certain parts of the API easier to use (specifically, locking and unlocking mutexes can be easily done in an exception safe way and condition variables are easier to use.)

Comment: Great information. I did not know anything about std::thread; I'll have a look through it. "fork() is not heavy on UNIX". I'm sorry for that statement; fork() isn't heavy on UNIX because UNIX handles processes really well. I mean "I don't want my application to sub-divide in multiple processes".

Comment: As I recall, fork() is quite heavy on Solaris. This may have changed, it has been years since I used it.

Comment: I think it's better on Solaris 10, but don't quote me on that. It's not as lightweight as fork in Linux, but still not as heavyweight as on Windows

Comment: I think this answer is wrong with it's assertion "pthreads is much more widely used". GNU pth is meant to be ported to platforms where no pthreads or pthreads-like implementation exists. Also, GNU pth can expose a pthreads API, so GNU pth itself is a pthreads implementation.

Comment: I've always thought of GNU pth as a beautifully engineered library. It might be good for use as a co-operative (preemptive) server for a limited client count. But it's just not going to scale like kernel threads on multiple cores, or the more light-weight solutions you might achieve with something like Boost.Asio. I think this answer is misleading wrt the use of `fork` - that's not a scalable solution for what's expected of a modern server.

Comment: I didn't say `fork` **should** be used, just that it's not terribly heavy. Maybe I should have only said on Linux though, as forking is pretty slow on AIX, and wasn't great (at one point) on Solaris.

Answer (score 3):

Gnu PTH is for a very limited use case: you want to use a multi-threaded implementation paradigm but you *don't* want to use multiple CPUs or cores and you don't want to rely on any OS or kernel-level support.  Since almost all general-purpose CPUs now have multiple cores, this use case is increasingly irrelevant.

Windows has a separate threading model from POSIX; if you want your application to be cross-platform it is best to use a cross-platform threading library such as boost::thread.

Comment: ...or you DON'T want to think about thread sync, DON'T want to get excessive context switches, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

I think GNUs PTH is meaned for C in the first place. You can use it on C++ too but C++ have its own anyway.

There are quite some applications using pth like low-level burning tools (and so GUI-Tools like K3B and Brasero depend on pth), also GnuPG uses PTH, the package management of Archlinux and some multimedia stuff.

On Windows its always a bit complicated. Microsoft did never get over the fact that C is the Programming Language from/for UNIX-Systems and so is suffering the NIH Symptome (Not Invented Here)

So they do a lot of stuff without any advantage just to be different.

If you use an Application which should run everywhere and its not low-level, use Qt with its QThreads and QThreadPool

1. Its 100% the same on all operating systems
2. You need much less code

If you write an "low-level" application i recommend to split your applications into backends and frontends and write a own backend for each OS and use the library which will do the least problems.